# xDebug профилирование, PhpStorm и Composer

Tags: php, xdebug

Здравствуйте.

Хочу провести профилирование PHP скрипта в `windows`. Запускаю скрипт в PhpStorm-е, просто указав в конфигурации интерпетатор.

Вот часть настроек профайлера:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable=On
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="D:\"
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=On
xdebug.profiler_output_name="cachegrind.out.%R-%t"
```

Профилирование идет. Скрипт выполняется заметно дольше. В `D:\` создается файл, вроде бы все норм. Но при открытии этого файла через `WinCacheGrind` выдает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю, это из-за композера. Кто-то сталкивался с такой ошибкой?

Comment: вы можете использовать xhprof для профилирования приложений, с построением графиков вызовов и времени, и стэка вызовов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это из-за того что файл имеет слишком большой размер.

Попробуйте открыть в [kcachegrind](https://sourceforge.net/projects/precompiledbin/).

Comment: Требует файлы `callgrind`, а создаются `cachegrind`. *Udated*: а, переименовал - всё норм)